# how to insert multiple records into a sqlite table with increasing the ID column

Tags: c#

I want to insert a view  records in a sqlite database. below is what i have so far. This does not work, the databse gets locked
how to get the max id from a table and then insert a few records while increasing the id?

first i want to get the max id fom the table:

```
private void button_voeg_gebuiker_toe_Click(object sender, EventArgs exp)
        {
            try
            {//Hoogste ID bepalen
                if (getMaxID() >= -1)
                {
                    insertIntoUsers(); //insert mag starten
                }
                else
                {
                    //logging...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               //logging...
            }
        }
```

the getMaxId funtion:

```
public int getMaxID()
        {
            try
            {
                connectToDatabase();
                string sql = "select max(ID) as ID from USERS";
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        id = reader.GetInt32(0);  
                        id += 1;
                        m_dbConnection.Close();
                        return id;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string fout = e.ToString();  //bad solution
                    id = 1;
                    return id;  //if table is emtpy then return id=1
                }
                return -1;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               //logging...
                m_dbConnection.Close();
                return -1;
            }
        }



private void connectToDatabase()
        {
            Class_check_app_environment locatieDB = new Class_check_app_environment();
            try
            {
                m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + locatieDB.Get_Applicatiepad() + Form_Main.DataMap + Form_Main.GebruikersDatabase + ";" + Form_Main.SqliteVersie + ";");
                m_dbConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

The insert function:

```
private void insertIntoUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                m_dbConnection.Open();
                string sql = "insert into USERS (ID, GEBRUIKER, WACHTWOORD, ROL) values (@ID, @GEBRUIKERNAAM, @WACHTWOORD, @ROL)";  
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ID", id));  
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@GEBRUIKERNAAM", gebruikernaam));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@WACHTWOORD", wachtwoord));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ROL", rol));

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                m_dbConnection.Close();  //connectie weer sluiten
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //logging...
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the `ID` column is a `PRIMARY KEY`, you can insert your data without the `ID` column. `INSERT INTO Users (GEBRUIKER, WACHTWOORD, ROL)`... SQLite will increase the ID itself.

Comment: @Wudge: I think you are confusing primary key with identity.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: SQLite handles a column that is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as an identity-column. Using `AUTOINCREMENT` as it is done in MS SQL Server is not needed.

Comment: @Wudge Thanks, I've learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your table structure for more clarifications.. 
your saying your database get locked when you retrieving Max id, for this you can use SHARED lock will be acquired when the first SELECT statement is executed. Shared lock means that the database may be read but not written. A RESERVED lock will be acquired when the first INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement is executed. 
**You can refer this link for more information about sqlite no lock** - https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Comment: I found it. The reader must be closed. First i use getmaxid and then i use the select query. when i close the reader in getmaxid and then use the select query there is no database lock anymore.